# PySpark how to sort array of struct with 2 elements

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have the following schema

```
|-- node: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- score: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- toID: string (nullable = true)

+-----------
 node|
+-------------
|[[57753, XV0912938...|
|[[51959, 02384848...|
|[[63487, 898898989...|
```

I want to sort based on `score` and select top 10 `toID` . What is an easy pyspark way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

`sort_array(<array column>, asc=False)` function can be used to sort the elements within the array. If the elements are structs, the array is sorted based on the first field in the struct. Since, the score field is the first field in the struct, you can directly sort the array of structs using this function.

Here's an example to get the top 5 IDs based on the score within the struct.

Suppose your data looks like the following

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|arr_of_structs                                                                                                                          |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
|[{270, foo0}, {237, foo1}, {2440, foo2}, {2059, foo3}, {3960, foo4}, {3009, foo5}, {842, foo6}, {1043, foo7}, {852, foo8}, {3925, foo9}]|
|[{1028, bar0}, {2571, bar1}, {1682, bar2}, {2543, bar3}, {689, bar4}, {11, bar5}, {1, bar6}, {740, bar7}, {113, bar8}, {701, bar9}]     |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+

root
 |-- arr_of_structs: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- _1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- _2: string (nullable = true)
```

The code would be very simple

- use `sort_array` to sort the array of structs
- use `slice` function to retain the first `N` elements in the sorted array.

```py
data_sdf. \
    withColumn('arr_of_structs_top5', func.slice(func.sort_array('arr_of_structs', asc=False), 1, 5)). \
    withColumn('top5_id_only', func.expr('transform(arr_of_structs_top5, x -> x._2)')). \
    drop('arr_of_structs'). \
    show(truncate=False)

# +----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
# |arr_of_structs_top5                                                   |top5_id_only                  |
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
# |[{3960, foo4}, {3925, foo9}, {3009, foo5}, {2440, foo2}, {2059, foo3}]|[foo4, foo9, foo5, foo2, foo3]|
# |[{2571, bar1}, {2543, bar3}, {1682, bar2}, {1028, bar0}, {740, bar7}] |[bar1, bar3, bar2, bar0, bar7]|
# +----------------------------------------------------------------------+------------------------------+
```